# Selenium - How to hover on a point with double/float coordinates?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, Selenium's `Actions` class only has this as a function for `moveToElement`:

```
public Actions moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset {
    action.addAction(new MoveToOffsetAction(mouse, (Locatable) toElement, xOffset, yOffset));
    return this;
}
```

However, the website's coordinates have `float` coordinates (ex. **(200.5,0)**). Is there any way I can hover to this specific point?

[EDIT]:
This is the method I'm trying to do. Works perfectly fine with whole number coordinates

```
public void hoverPt(String xAxis) throws Exception //Use Build Interaction
{
int x = Integer.parseInt(xAxis);
WebDriver driver = WebManager.getDriver();
WebElement lineGraph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("[xpath of chart plane]"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(lineGraph, x, 0).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

The **String xAxis** was fetched from an excel sheet, then I just parsed it to int so I can parameterize it to **moveToElement**.

Comment: Can you consider updating us your work, exact steps and the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB edited the question

Comment: I have an Answer for you but before providing the solution I need to check if it works properly. Can you provide me a demo URL/Link to validate my Answer? Thanks

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB. Sorry i cannot find any demo site that has charts. I also cannot give the link I'm working on due to confidentiality. Maybe it's ok to post your code here, and I validate it myself, would that be fine? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot class for this:

```
    Point p = toElement.getLocation();
    int x = p.getX();
    int y = p.getY();
    Dimension d = toElement.getSize();
    int h = d.getHeight();
    int w = d.getWidth();
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(x + (w/2), y+(h/2) +80);
```